# commit values on SelectedItems of ComboBoxes in Coded UI Tests

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, parameters, coded-ui-tests

Is there any possibility to commit a value of a variable (declared as string) on a SelectedItem of a ComboBox in a Coded UI Test?

for instance:

```
private const string SALUTATION = "Mr.";

...

CommonMap.SalutationParams.LstEntriesSelectedItemsAsString = SALUTATION;
CommonMap.Salutation();

...
```

I am getting an error because of trying this:

```
Result Message: 
Test method CodedUIClassicCommon.Common.CodedUITestsCommon.CodedUIClassicCommonNeuerBenutzerWeiblich threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of SelectedItemsAsString with value "A.Frau/SgF"' on the control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
ControlType:  'List'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F008
TestCleanup method CodedUIClassicCommon.Common.CodedUITestsCommon.MyTestCleanUp threw exception. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
Name:  'Neu Ctrl+N'
ControlType:  'MenuItem'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F002.
```

I have searched in google for such a problem but i couldn't resolve it.

thanks for any help.

eric

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
CommonMap.SalutationParams.LstEntriesSelectedItemsAsString = SALUTATION;
```

Have a dot between the LstEntries and SelectedItemsAsString?

```
CommonMap.SalutationParams.LstEntries.SelectedItemsAsString = SALUTATION;
```

Can you confirm that the object you are trying to click on is in fact visible? If you are clicking on a MenuItem that is hidden because the list needs to be expanded/scrolled/etc it will throw an error. This would be my first thought.

Also, I prefer to use the PerformSelect of the MenuItem rather than reassigning the value.